# Retrieve the the background color of Office365 calendar events

Tags: java, outlook, office365

[image]

I need to get the pink background color of the events in office365 calendar.
I tried to
[Load my events](https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/events)
[Load my calendars](https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/calendars/)

But I cannot find any attribute pertaining to the pink background color.
How can I get the pink background color of the events in office365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the background color through the API, this is just a styling thing. What exactly do you want the color for? How about you just grab its hexadecimal value and use it in your own styling?

Comment: in my application in am retrieving all the events in office365 calender. i now need to display my events in the same color as that in office365. 
 
I can change the color of the calendars to any color like blue red etc.... How can I grab its hexadecimal value dynamically through the office365 api ?

Comment: I don't think an API to achieve this functionality exists today, sorry.